# How to fix Clock? For Chess. Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a Chess clock for my chess project. In chess there are time formats 5|5 is where each player (white and black) is granted a general 5 minutes, so when either player makes a move it adds 5 seconds to the clock. So 15|10 is 15 minutes in general and 10 seconds per move.

My code:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 300, 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Fonts
Font = pygame.font.SysFont("Trebuchet MS", 25)

class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, screen, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def setColor(self, new_color):
        self.color = new_color

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if self.x < pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if self.y < pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def main():
    global Second, Minute
    running = True

    Black = 0, 0, 0
    White = 255, 255, 255

    Second = 0
    Minute = 0
    five_five = False
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while running:
        five_five_button = Button(White, 150, 150, 40, 20, '5|5')
        five_plus_five = Button(White, 150, 180, 40, 20, "+5 secs")
        five_five_button.draw(screen, None)
        five_plus_five.draw(screen, None)
        pygame.display.update()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if five_five_button.isOver(e.pos):
                    five_five = True
                if five_plus_five.isOver(e.pos):
                    Second = +5
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pass  # if you want to add keys to test things easier

         if five_five:
            Minute = 5
            Second = 0
            five_five = False
        if not five_five:
            if Second == 0:
                Second = 58
                Minute = Minute - 1
                Second += 2

        time.sleep(1)
        Second -= 1
        # Minute
        MinuteFont = Font.render(str(Minute).zfill(2), True, Black)
        MinuteFontR = MinuteFont.get_rect()
        MinuteFontR.center = (50, 60)
        # Second
        SecondFont = Font.render(":" + str(Second).zfill(2), True, Black)
        SecondFontR = SecondFont.get_rect()
        SecondFontR.center = (80, 60)

        screen.fill(White)

        # Timer
        #    while Time==0: this will cause a crash !
        screen.blit(SecondFont, SecondFontR)
        screen.blit(MinuteFont, MinuteFontR)
        pygame.display.flip()
        Clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issues I face:

So let's say the player makes a move and the time is at 4:59. We want to add 5 secs. So it adds 5 seconds so 4:64 so it'll minus a minute so 3:04. I don't know how to fix that.

Another is that whenever you want to add 5 seconds or whatever it'll never goes past 59 and add those seconds on to the total and add a minute.

I've worked hours on this believe it or not figuring out the simple things. I've looked up how to make clocks and things in python (or pygame) and I always get adding clocks. I never found a clock that adds time, but also counts down at the same time.

Whenever I even try to load or click one of the buttons. It takes a few seconds to register it. So if you can help me figure this all out or find out a better way to make it I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Name changes

First of all, I would rename some variables to better convey their meaning (given that some weren't immediately obvious), so I changed these:

```
five_five_button -> reset_button
five_plus_five -> add_button
Second -> seconds
Minute -> minutes
Black -> BLACK
White -> WHITE
```

### Button creation

Next, I don't think you need to re-create your two buttons every frame. Just once should be enough to enable them to be drawn, so I moved them as shown:

```py
# moved to here
reset_button = Button(White, 150, 150, 40, 20, '5|5')
add_button = Button(White, 150, 180, 40, 20, "+5 secs")
while running:
    # removed from here
    # reset_button = Button(White, 150, 150, 40, 20, '5|5')
    # add_button = Button(White, 150, 180, 40, 20, "+5 secs")

    # ... rest of loop code ...
```

### Minutes and seconds timer

Next, I like what you were going for with the reset and adding time code, but think in a scenario like this it actually just makes things more complicated. So I removed these `if` statements:

```py
if five_five:
    minutes = 5
    seconds = 0
    five_five = False
if not five_five:
    if seconds == 0:
        seconds = 58
        minutes = minutes - 1
        seconds += 2
```

and moved their logic straight into the pygame event handling loop code:

```py
if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if reset_button.isOver(e.pos):
        minutes = 5
        seconds = 0
    if add_button.isOver(e.pos):
        seconds += 5
```

but this also means that we don't have any logic to handle what happens if the seconds goes "out of bounds", so I wrote the following to happen right after our pygame event loop:

```py
while seconds >= 60:
    seconds -= 60
    minutes += 1
while seconds < 0:
    seconds += 60
    minutes -= 1
```

### Splitting into functions

The refactored code is almost complete, but before that I want to split our code into functions to help maintainability and modularilty. I also really like the use of classes for the buttons.

First I want a "draw everything on the screen" function:

```py
def draw_screen():
    global WHITE, BLACK

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # buttons
    reset_button.draw(screen, None)
    add_button.draw(screen, None)

    # minutes tezt
    minutesFont = Font.render(str(minutes).zfill(2), True, BLACK)
    minutesFontR = minutesFont.get_rect()
    minutesFontR.center = (50, 60)
    screen.blit(minutesFont, minutesFontR)

    # seconds text
    secondsFont = Font.render(":" + str(seconds).zfill(2), True, BLACK)
    secondsFontR = secondsFont.get_rect()
    secondsFontR.center = (80, 60)
    screen.blit(secondsFont, secondsFontR)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

### Timer

The reason you feel that the buttons take forever to respond is because **pygame can only respond to button presses *once a second***. This is because of your `time.sleep(1)`, meaning that your event loop is only run once a second. We will need a non-blocking way of decreasing the seconds timer by `1` once a second:

```py
previousTime = time.time()
# ...
while running:
    # ...
    if time.time() - previousTime > 1:
        previousTime = time.time()
        seconds -= 1
```

### Final code

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 300, 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Fonts
Font = pygame.font.SysFont("Trebuchet MS", 25)

class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, screen, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def setColor(self, new_color):
        self.color = new_color

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if self.x < pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if self.y < pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def draw_screen(minutes, seconds):
    global WHITE, BLACK

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # buttons
    reset_button.draw(screen, None)
    add_button.draw(screen, None)

    # minutes tezt
    minutesFont = Font.render(str(minutes).zfill(2), True, BLACK)
    minutesFontR = minutesFont.get_rect()
    minutesFontR.center = (50, 60)
    screen.blit(minutesFont, minutesFontR)

    # seconds text
    secondsFont = Font.render(":" + str(seconds).zfill(2), True, BLACK)
    secondsFontR = secondsFont.get_rect()
    secondsFontR.center = (80, 60)
    screen.blit(secondsFont, secondsFontR)

    pygame.display.flip()


def fix_time(minutes, seconds):
    while seconds >= 60:
        seconds -= 60
        minutes += 1
    while seconds < 0:
        seconds += 60
        minutes -= 1
    return minutes, seconds


def handle_events(minutes, seconds, reset_button, add_button):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if reset_button.isOver(e.pos):
                    minutes = 5
                    seconds = 0
                if add_button.isOver(e.pos):
                    seconds += 5
    return minutes, seconds

def main():
    global seconds, minutes
    running = True

    BLACK = 0, 0, 0
    WHITE = 255, 255, 255

    seconds = 0
    minutes = 0
    previousTime = time.time()
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    reset_button = Button(WHITE, 150, 150, 40, 20, '5|5')
    add_button = Button(WHITE, 150, 180, 40, 20, "+5 secs")
    while running:
        
        minutes, seconds = handle_events(minutes, seconds, reset_button, add_button)

        if time.time() - previousTime > 1:
            previousTime = time.time()
            seconds -= 1

        minutes, seconds = fix_time(minutes, seconds)

        draw_screen(minutes, seconds):

        Clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Thoughts

I haven't run any of the code, but the thought, intent and improvement is still just as valid. There are still improvements that could be made to the code (having to return `minutes` and `seconds`, and passing `reset_button` and `add_button` as parameters, are both "not great") so feel free to use my example as inspiration.

Comment: You actually fixed the issues. I will fix the parameters. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

So let's just rebuild the block where you handle minute changes.

Things we need to implement:

1. Every tick, needs to check if seconds has gone over 59 or under 0
2. If over, then we need to add a minute
3. If under, then we need to subtract a minute
4. In both cases, we need to reset the seconds

We can do all that with simple if statements. Have a look at the following.

I am also going to move the seconds tick to be before the check, to make our math a bit more clear (Change the time, and *then* fix it)

```py
Second -= 1
if not five_five:
    if Second < 0:
        Minute -= 1
        Second += 60    # Since Seconds will probably be -1
    elif Second > 59:
        Minute += 1
        Second -= 60
```

Comment: That helps, it does make it better, but what happens if the player makes a move at 4:59 adding 5 secs. What happens it should be 5:04, but it turns into 4:04. So I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Does that still happen? With my code, the Minute should be going up if time is added, not down.